# Two dotted division symbol

Tags: texmaker

I'm making a report about progression in another language. Is there any way to make two dotted (both up and low) ÷ symbol?

I have searched in many things and i can't find it.

Comment: `\div` gives the symbol.

Comment: *with two dots.

Comment: Two dots horizontally or vertically?

Comment: 2*2 dots, with a horizontal line in center

Comment: @TumendemberelZolboo: How are the dots arranged horizontally?

Comment: does this mean something different from the unicode symbol for geometric proportion (U+223A)?

Comment: Yes!@barbarabeeton it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want this as a binary operator.  Then the following will work at different sizes.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ddiv}{\mathbin{{\div}\mkern-10mu{\div}}}

\begin{document}

\( A \div B \ddiv C ^ {D \div E \ddiv F^{G \div H \ddiv I}} \)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a Unicode symbol:

```
∺ U+223A Geometric proportion
```

### LuaTeX/XeTeX

The Unicode math fonts for LuaTeX or XeLaTeX usually contain this symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
  #1&%
  \setmathfont{#1}% or via font name #2
  $\dotsminusdots\div$%
}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \test{Latin Modern Math}{latinmodern-math.otf}\\
  \test{Asana Math}{Asana-Math.otf}\\
  \test{XITS Math}{xits-math.otf}\\
  \test{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}{texgyrebonum-math.otf}\\
  \test{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}{texgyrepagella-math.otf}\\
  \test{TeX Gyre Schola Math}{texgyreschola-math.otf}\\
  \test{TeX Gyre Termes Math}{texgyretermes-math.otf}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: unicode-math]

### Poor man's version

The following example constructs the symbol from the minus sign and the dot:

- The symbol automatically follows the math style with its size.
- It is assumed that the side bearings are the same for the minus sign and the dot. Then the dots and the ends of the minus sign will be aligned correctly.
- The bottom dots are put on the base line.
- The minus on the math axis is a mirror axis for the dots, if the character bounding box for the dot is correct, especially its height.

Depending on the math font, the dots in symbol `\div` might differ, e.g. larger than the normal dot or greater distance from the horizontal line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\dotsminusdots}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@dotsminusdots{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@dotsminusdots}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}% \ht0: math axis
  \sbox2{$#1.\m@th$}% \ht2: height of dot
    % Character bounding box of \cdot is wrong
    % in some fonts (e.g., Computer Modern)
  \sbox4{%
    \raise\dimexpr2\ht0-\ht2\rlap{\unhcopy2}%
    \unhcopy2 %
  }%
  \rlap{\unhcopy4}%
  {-}%
  \llap{\unhcopy4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  x \dotsminusdots y_{x \dotsminusdots y_{x \dotsminusdots y}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way, with stacks.  If you need it with different kerning, or to work in script style or scriptscriptstyle, see below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\ddiv{\mathop{\stackunder[-1.6pt]{\stackon[-1.6pt]{-\kern-6.5pt-}{..}}{..}}}
\begin{document}
$A\div B\ddiv A$

$A\ddiv B\div A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the dots to be of a comparable size to those of the `\div` symbol, then this variation would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\stackMath
\def\DD{\scalebox{1.2}{.}\scalebox{1.2}{.}}
\def\ddiv{\mathop{\stackunder[-1.8pt]{\stackon[-1.8pt]{-\kern-6.5pt-}{\DD}}{\DD}}}
\begin{document}
$A\div B\ddiv A$

$A\ddiv B\div A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it to scale to different mathstyles, here is an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\DD{\scalebox{1.2}{$\SavedStyle.$}%
  \kern-2pt\kern2\LMpt\scalebox{1.2}{$\SavedStyle.$}}
\def\ddiv{\mathop{\ThisStyle{\stackunder[-.8pt-\LMpt]{%
  \stackon[-.8pt-\LMpt]{%
  \SavedStyle-\kern-4pt\kern-2.5\LMpt-}{\DD}}{\DD}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\div B\ddiv A$\par
$A\ddiv B\div A$\par
$\scriptstyle A\ddiv B$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A\ddiv B$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or with altered kerning more in line with the unicode symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\stackMath
\def\DD{\scalebox{1.2}{$\SavedStyle.$}%
  \kern-2pt\kern4\LMpt\scalebox{1.2}{$\SavedStyle.$}}
\def\ddiv{\mathop{\ThisStyle{\stackunder[-.8pt-\LMpt]{%
  \stackon[-.8pt-\LMpt]{%
  \SavedStyle-\kern-4pt\kern-2.5\LMpt-}{\DD}}{\DD}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\div B\ddiv A$\par
$A\ddiv B\div A$\par
$\scriptstyle A\ddiv B$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle A\ddiv B$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]